# What is the default port for Google cloud pub/sub?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, java-8, spring-cloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to add the firewall rule for my server box to connect with GCP pub sub but unable to find the default port for GCP in its documentation. Can anyone please share the default port or help to point to the documentation which discuss about the default port for GCP pub/sub?

Comment: Are you using events or polling Pub/Sub? Push delivery uses HTTP POST (HTTPS port 443). If you are polling, then you do not need to open an ingress port. Note: I have not tried specifying a push-endpoint to a different port number than 443 but it might be possible. Edit your question with details on how you are using Pub/Sub.